# "Instantiate" vs "substantiate" vs "reify"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences, word-usage

Do they mean the same thing?  I just came across *instantiate* for the first time in an email by someone who said a certain action **instantiates charity.**  I think the person should have used *reify* instead but now I'm not sure.  And then there is *substantiate.*  I want to reply back to them but since I have to address that issue, I want to know the usage so that if I use *substantiate* instead, it won't sound weird.

Dictionary.com gives

- *instantiate:* to provide an instance of or concrete evidence in support of (a theory, concept, claim, or the like)."
- *substantiate:* to establish by proof or competent evidence; to give substantial existence to.
- *reify:* to convert into or regard as a concrete thing, like reify a concept

Comment: I think you should probably provide more of a concrete example, and what the intended meaning was. Those three words have distinct meanings, and I suspect that none of them are appropriate.

Comment: Just a warning that most people don’t know what *reify* means: it’s the only  *-fy* verb in the English language that when stripped of its *-fy* suffix leaves you with something that is no longer related to any recognizable English word. And no, *res publica* does not count.

Comment: You might be interested in the Computer Science usage of [instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science))

Comment: There is not sufficient context provided to make a worthwhile suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions provided by Dictionary.com are rather similar but the words are not.

To **substantiate** is to support with evidence; nothing real needs to have happened. To **instantiate** is to manifest; the concept doesn't necessarily want for more proof. **Reify** similarly means to manifest but *lasts longer*. An instantiation is an *instance*; a reification is a *reality*. This is a bit of a stretch, because an instantiation doesn't need to be momentary, but it is an *occurence* whereas a reification is often more sustained. See the examples below for reify: verbal constructs and a race-based logic.

Let's look to NOAD:

> **instantiate**
>
> • represent as or by an instance: *a study of two groups who seemed to instantiate productive aspects of this.*
>
> • (be instantiated) *Philosophy* (of a universal or abstract concept) have an instance; be represented by an actual example.
>
> **substantiate**
>
> • provide evidence to support or prove the truth of: they had found nothing to substantiate the allegations.
>
> **reify**
>
> • make (something abstract) more concrete or real: *these instincts are, in humans, reified as verbal constructs.*

Notice that the main verb in *instantiate*'s definition is *represent*. In *substantiate*'s it is *prove*.

*Reify* takes an abstract, broader concept and makes it real with a specific concrete application. Merriam Webster gives the following example:

> the diversity rationale also insultingly assumes that black students bring a black "point of view," Asians an Asian one and so on, thus *reifying* the very barriers of race and ethnicity that affirmative action is meant to erase.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that the difference is slight, but extant. If you consider the related words, "instance" and "substance," to instantiate would be to prove the (possible) *instance* of a thing, and to *substantiate* would be to make the claim of something substantial. (Reify, I'm less sure of.)

I'm not sure, but I don't think that instantiate was the correct word in the context of the email you received.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that instantiate is more related to abstract proof while substantiate would be of substance, like documents, recordings etc... Reify is the conversion from instantiating to substantiating